# Use appendTo in Kendo UI for Angular window component

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I need to use `appendTo` in the Window component of Kendo UI for Angular. This feature was available in the original jQuery version, any ideas if this is feasible?

```
<kendo-window [top]="100" 
              [left]="100" 
              [appendTo]="'body'"    // <-- this throws an exception
              [width]="300">
       <div>Some Element</div>
</kendo-window>
```

Comment: Why do you need it? The `kendo-window` in angular is appended wherever you put the html. Does this not work for you?

Comment: I need it in this scenario: I want to open a form inside a form. I want this embedded form to be draggable in the entire screen, not only within the first form. If I append it to body I can achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this directive on the element:

```
[popupSettings]="{appendTo: popupContainer}"
```